# What are the last two digits of $3^{100}11^{50}+7^{518}$?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

What are the last two digits of $3^{100}11^{50}+7^{518}$?

I know that to find the last two digits implies that you are essentially finding the remainder when divided by $100$.

Can I simplify $3^{100}$ to $3$ mod $1$ by dividing both the exponent and $100$ (which are the same in this case) by $100$?

Also, how would I simplify $7^{518}$ if that were the case?

Any help is appreciated; thanks!

Comment: you use the tag modular-arithmetic, do you know [Euler's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem)?

Comment: "*Can I simplify $3^{100}\pmod{100}$ to $3\pmod{1}$ by dividing both the exponent and $100$ by $100$?*"  No.  $a^{b}\pmod{n}$ is not the same thing as $a^{b/n}\pmod{1}$.

Comment: Also: helps to remark that $3^{100}=9^{50}$.

Comment: Hint: consider $$3^{100}\cdot 11^{50}+7^{518}$$ $$\mod 100$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner That is hardly a hint since the OP already noted this in the post.  Also, you went and changed the exponent of the $7$, most likely accidentally.

Comment: What you need to do is to find the residues modulo $4$ and $25$ and then combine them by the Chinese Remainder Theorem to get the residue modulo $100$. Finding the residue mod $4$ is easy since $3,11,7$ are all $\equiv -1$ modulo $4$. For the residue modulo $25$, use Euler's totient theorem.

Comment: This number is:
`576480640609510965066314482828672556401765672733423600548872826759892460943865480929895994882998931876312519596132082825169493506064584113366084711908448046665868639062950578870313565923047691366994573232598945135723569771431093432511719358071938962883275316399241835325840273366037335806035506031473017932615726910552169773872794599289312353899646508984525940456634363012995394996045038153933633619124906481565859968322259813064504855450` Indeed, two last numbers are $50$ .

Comment: @macy After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

As you suggested, we want some $0\leq n \leq 99$ such that
$$ 
n \equiv 3^{100} \cdot 11^{50} + 7^{518} \pmod{100}.
$$
As noted by lulu in the comments, we first observe that $3^{100} = 9^{50}$. Hence, we have
\begin{align}
n &\equiv 3^{100} \cdot 11^{50} + 7^{518} \pmod{100} \\ &= 9^{50} \cdot 11^{50} + 7^{518} \\ &= 99^{50} + 7^{518}
\end{align}

Note that $99^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{100}$ and $7^4 \equiv 1 \pmod{100}$, so
\begin{align}
n &\equiv 99^{50} + 7^{518} \pmod{100}\\ &= (99^2)^{25} + (7^4)^{129} \cdot 7^2 \\ &\equiv 1^{25} + 1^{129} \cdot 7^2  \pmod{100} \\& = 1 + 49 =50. \end{align}

Therefore, the last two digits of $3^{100} \cdot 11^{50} + 7^{518}$ are $5$ and $0$.

Answer (score -1):

$$ 3^{100}11^{50} = 9^{50}11^{50} = 99^{50}$$

$$ 99^{50} (mod 100) = (-1)^{50} (mod 100) = ((-1)^2)^{25} = 1^{25} = 1$$

$$ 7^4 (mod 100) = 2401 (mod 100) = 1 $$

$$ 7^{518} (mod 100)= 7^2(7^{4})^{129} (mod 100) = 7^2 = 49 $$

$$ 1 + 49 = 50 $$

Then, the result is: $$50$$

Comment: $\large \bmod 100\!:\,\ 7^{\Large 4} \equiv (50\!-\!1)^{\Large 2} \equiv \color{#c00}{50^2}\!-\color{#0a0}{2(50)}+1\,\equiv\, \color{#c00}0-\color{#0a0}0+1\,\equiv\, 1\ \ $

Answer (score -1):

As $\phi(100)=100\cdot\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{4}{5}=40$, we know (by Euler’s Theorem) that
$$7^{40}\equiv1\pmod{100}$$
Hence,
$$7^{518}\cdot7^2=7^{520}=(7^{40})^{13}\equiv1\pmod{100}$$
And as the inverse of $7\pmod{100}$ is $43$,
$$7^{518}\equiv1\cdot43^2=1849\equiv49\pmod{100}$$

Now we can calculate
$$3^{100}\cdot11^{50}+7^{518}$$
$$\equiv(9\cdot11)^{50}+49\pmod{100}$$
$$\equiv(-1)^{50}+49\pmod{100}$$
$$\equiv1+49\pmod{100}$$
$$\equiv50\pmod{100}$$

So the last two digits of $3^{100}\cdot11^{50}+7^{518}$ are $50$.